# Fetching Relationship Model Data

Tags: laravel

I have the Below Table Structure

```
Users table
    id- integer
    name-string

Casefiles table
    id- integer
    user_id- foreign_key
    name-string

Followups table
    id- integer
    date- date
    casefile_id-foreign_key
```

I'm using the below Relationship between this models
User.php

```
public function casefiles()
    {
      if ($this->hasRole(['sales_executive'])) {
        return Casefile::where('user_id', $this->id);
      }
    }
```

Casefile.php

```
public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function followups()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\FollowUp');
    }
```

Followup.php

```
public function casefile()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Casefile');
    }
```

I want to fetch Users followups directly. How can i achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `hasManyThrough()` in your `User.php` you can add this,

```
 public function followUps()
 {
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\FollowUp','App\Casefile');
 }
```

then you can normally call the followups using `User::with('followUps')->find(1)->followUps`

I have noticed that you are checking role in your relationship `$this->hasRole(['sales_executive']` this may occur error as you are not if the statement is false. I think you take another approached and handle that as well. for more information on hasManyThrough prefer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: first argument passed to hasManyThrough is Casefile But i need Followups not Casefile

Comment: I have edited the question check whether is it working properly

Answer (score 0):

This should be the case for a [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) Relationship.

In your case it should be

```
// Followups migration
Schema::create('followups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('casefile_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('casefile_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('casefiles');
});

// Casefile migration
Schema::create('casefiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
       ->references('id')
       ->on('users');
});

// User.php

public function followups() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(FollowUp::class, Casefile::class);
}

// YourController.php
$user = User::all()->first();
dd($user->followups);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I have improved my answer with full working code, tested on my machine in this very moment :)